# Opengl : Render To Cubemap?

Tags: c++, opengl, reflection, glm-math

I am trying to render 3d scene to a cubemap but the cubemap only renders the skybox, here is my RenderToCubemap function:

```
GLuint RenderToCubemap(glm::vec3 position, float resolution, float nearPlane, float farPlane)
{
    unsigned int CM_FBO;
    unsigned int textureID;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &CM_FBO);
    glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, textureID);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGBA, resolution, resolution, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    // attach depth texture as FBO's depth buffer
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, CM_FBO);
    glFramebufferTexture(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, textureID, 0);

    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        std::cout << "ERROR::FRAMEBUFFER:: Framebuffer is not complete!" << std::endl;
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    glm::mat4 shadowProj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(90.0f), (float)resolution / (float)resolution, nearPlane, farPlane);
    std::vector<glm::mat4> shadowTransforms;
    shadowTransforms.push_back(shadowProj * glm::lookAt(position, position + glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f)));
    shadowTransforms.push_back(shadowProj * glm::lookAt(position, position + glm::vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f)));
    shadowTransforms.push_back(shadowProj * glm::lookAt(position, position + glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)));
    shadowTransforms.push_back(shadowProj * glm::lookAt(position, position + glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f)));
    shadowTransforms.push_back(shadowProj * glm::lookAt(position, position + glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f)));
    shadowTransforms.push_back(shadowProj * glm::lookAt(position, position + glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f)));

    // Render scene to cubemap
    // --------------------------------
    glViewport(0, 0, (int)resolution, (int)resolution);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, CM_FBO);

    Camera capture_cam;
    capture_cam.temp_cam = true;
    capture_cam.projectionMatrix = shadowProj;
    capture_cam.transform.Position = position;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        capture_cam.viewMatrix = shadowTransforms[i];

        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, textureID, 0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        RenderScene(capture_cam);
    }

    return textureID;
}
```

RenderScene function :

```
void RenderScene(Camera& cam)
{
    glm::mat4 proj = cam.GetProjectionMatrix();
    glm::mat4 view = cam.GetViewMatrix();
    glm::vec3 viewPos = cam.transform.Position;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        Shader* shader = &materials.main_shader;

        shader ->use();
        shader ->SetMat4("projection", proj);
        shader ->SetMat4("view", view);
        shader ->SetVec3("CamPos", viewPos);

        // Render all meshs
        // ----------------------------------------------------
        for (size_t i = 0; i < Meshs.size(); i++)
        {
            if (Meshs[i].Material == nullptr)
                continue;

            Meshs[i].Material->setShaderProperties(shader);

            shader->SetMat4("model", Meshs[i].Transform);
            Meshs[i]->Draw();
       }    
    
    // render skybox 
    // ----------------------------------------------------
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);  // change depth function so depth test passes when values are equal to depth buffer's content
    Shader* bg = &materials.background;
    bg->use();
    bg->SetMat4("view", view);
    bg->SetMat4("projection", proj);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, envCubemap); 
    renderCube();
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS); // set depth function back to default
}
```

I am using RenderScene for main rendering and it works, but when i use it in renderToCubemap it shows only the skybox.

Any help or correction?

Comment: What is the point of attaching the cubemap texture to the framebuffer as a layered image if you're just going to overwrite that attachment by attaching each face later on? Also, your comment talks about a "depth texture", but your FBO doesn't have any depth buffer at all. So how exactly is that going to work?

Comment: ... as pointed out above, the depth test doesn't work, because the framebuffer has no depth buffer. Hence `renderCube()` overwrites everything that has been drawn before in the "Mesh" loop.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I found what the problem is in the "shadowTransforms" that I corrected by removing multiplication shadowProj on every glm::lookAt, also i added a depth buffer and now it works correctly, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have replaced "shadowTransforms" with :

```
    std::vector<glm::mat4> shadowTransforms;
    shadowTransforms.push_back(glm::lookAt(position, position + glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f)));
    shadowTransforms.push_back(glm::lookAt(position, position + glm::vec3(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f)));
    shadowTransforms.push_back(glm::lookAt(position, position + glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)));
    shadowTransforms.push_back(glm::lookAt(position, position + glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f)));
    shadowTransforms.push_back(glm::lookAt(position, position + glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f)));
    shadowTransforms.push_back(glm::lookAt(position, position + glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f)));
```

Also I have added a depth buffer:

```
unsigned int m_CubemapDepthRBO;
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &m_CubemapDepthRBO);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_CubemapDepthRBO);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, (int)resolution, (int)resolution);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, m_CubemapDepthRBO);
```

Now working properly, thank Nicole Polas and Rabbid76 for quick responses.